# error using <filesystem> header with cmake and g++10

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, c++20

I am using `#include<filesystem>` c++ standered library in my cmake project with c++20 and g++10 on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS

```
// properties.hpp
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
class File
{
private:
    std::filesystem::path m_filePath;
public:
    explicit File();
    ~File();
    void setPath(const std::string &p_fullPath);
};

// properties.cpp
#include "properties.hpp"

ff::prop::File::File() { this->setPath(""); }
ff::prop::File::~File() { this->setPath(""); }

void ff::prop::File::setPath(const std::string &p_fullPath)
{
    using namespace std::filesystem;
    if (p_fullPath == "")
        this->m_filePath = path();
    else
        this->m_filePath = path(p_fullPath);
}
```

My CMake configuration is as follows: -

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26 FATAL_ERROR)

### cmake settings
set(CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++-10)
cmake_language(GET_MESSAGE_LOG_LEVEL VERBOSE)
message("The c++ version is ${CXX_STANDARD} ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT "-Wall -Wextra -std=c++20")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT "-Wall")

### project setttings
project(ff  VERSION 0.0.1  LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
  app/main.cpp
  app/src/app.cpp
  app/src/properties.cpp
)
```

When i run `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -S . -B debug` I get the following output confirming hat the compiler version is running c++20: -

```
The c++ version is 20 /usr/bin/g++-10
-- Build spdlog: 1.11.0
-- Build type: Debug
-- Configuring done (0.3s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/projects/ff/debug
```

but when i run `cmake --build debug/` i get the following linker errors: -

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ff.dir/app/main.cpp.o
In file included from /home/projects/ff/app/headers/events/import.hpp:9,
                 from /home/projects/ff/app/headers/windows/file_win.hpp:12,
                 from /home/projects/ff/app/headers/windows/app_win.hpp:12,
                 from /home/projects/ff/app/headers/app.hpp:6,
                 from /home/projects/ff/app/main.cpp:1:
/home/projects/ff/app/headers/properties.hpp:27:18: error: ‘filesystem’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type
   27 |             std::filesystem::path m_filePath;
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/frameflow.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/frameflow.dir/app/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:457: CMakeFiles/frameflow.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

I have tried Using  `#include<experimental/filesystem>` with the same configuration while changing the `std::filesystem::path` to `std::experimental::filesystem::path` which results in a compilation but gives linker errs as it is not able to find the source of experimental filestrem.

My questions are,

1. considering c++20 on g++10 has support for filesystem header then why does it not compile
2. why does it compile with experimental/filesystem
3. what do i do?

without came taking a minimal example

```
// a.hpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

namespace ff::prop
{
    class File
    {
    private:
        std::filesystem::path m_filePath;
    public:
        explicit File();
        ~File();
        void setPath(const std::string &p_fullPath);
    };
} // namespace ff::prop
```

```
// a.cpp
#include "a.hpp"

ff::prop::File::File() { this->setPath(""); }
ff::prop::File::~File() { this->setPath(""); }

void ff::prop::File::setPath(const std::string &p_fullPath)
{
    using namespace std::filesystem;
    if (p_fullPath == "")
        this->m_filePath = path();
    else
        this->m_filePath = path(p_fullPath);
}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "a.hpp"

int main() {
    ff::prop::File f();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This when compiled with `g++-10 main.cpp a.cpp -o app -std=20`does compile.

To clarify : -
after running `cmake --system-information info.txt` i get the following `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER == "/usr/bin/c++"` but the compiler version uses 10.3.0 in both cases.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You need a newer `g++` which you might be able to get for 20.04 but I would also advise you to update to 22.04. There is a PPA on Launchpad with this toolchain; alternatively the LLVM project has an `apt` repo with nightlies so you could try a newer `clang++`.  (It's worth it, `filesystem` in C++20 is very cool!)

Comment: seems to work fine on godbolt https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hf4WaeToY...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The normal g++10 distributions have `std::filesystem` by default. Some embedded dists. don't though, but that's not a matter of getting a _newer_ `g++`.

Comment: Thanks! @DirkEddelbuettel but i had downloaded the g++ compiler using ```sudo apt install g++10``` as the default for Ubuntu 20 was g++9. when I do ```g++-10 version``` it shows the version as 10.3.0. Is there a newer version available in Ubuntu 22? Anyways i'll checkout LLVM for this

Comment: @DhairyaGupta You don't need a newer version. The Ubuntu 20.04 g++10 distribution has it built-in, so that's not the problem. I'm thinking that _maybe_ the lack of header guards in your header files could be the problem even if I don't "see it" clearly. Just try adding `#pragma once` at the top of all your `.hpp` files.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have added ```#pragma once``` in my header. i just didn't show it as i thought it wouldn't be relevant

Comment: _All_ your headers?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yup all my header files

Comment: Ok, then try to condense it down to a [mre] with as few and short files as possible that can be used to reproduce the problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with g++10 and show the full content of those files in the question.

Comment: Does the include work without cmake? `g++-10 -std=c++20 somefile.cpp`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja i guess It does compile with a minimal example if i don't use cmake.

Comment: still cannot reproduce with your new attempt at a "[mre]" on godbolt. https://godbolt.org/z/rxMhj3Mvz. "_This when compiled with g++-10 main.cpp a.cpp -o app -std=20does compile tho??_" ... then it's not a [mre]. Give us an actual [mre]. I also suggest you show us the full output of your CMake configure command. I want to see what CMake _itself_ (not your `message` call) says about the compiler identification / selection

Comment: @TedLyngmo It does work with Cmake too now with the minimal example. I don't know what else to say

Comment: Ok, so your minimal example _does_ work with both g++10 and CMake? That's good news. Now you have to figure out what it is in your code (or CMake) that breaks it. Either you start building up your project from scratch and test compile between every little addition you make - or you go backwards and remove a small part at a time and test compile between every removal. Eventually, you'll find the culprit.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see now my cmake was giving the following after running ```cmake --system-information info.txt``` : -
```
CMAKE_SYSTEM_INFO_FILE == "Platform/Linux"
CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME == "Linux"
CMAKE_SYSTEM == "Linux-5.15.0-73-generic"
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER == "/usr/bin/c++"
CMAKE_C_COMPILER == "/usr/bin/cc"
CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC == "1"
CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX == "1"```
How do i make to use g++-10??

Comment: 1) Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. 2) show us the output of `/usr/bin/c++ --version`

Comment: @DhairyaGupta [How to choose the default gcc and g++ version? @ ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version)

Comment: @starball the output is : -
```
c++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```
my bad, ill edit the clarifications

Comment: @TedLyngmo as suggested by `starball`, after the output: c++ one also has the same version as g++-10. Also I dont want to change the default g++ compiler. i just wanted to use it for this project

Comment: It seems `/usr/bin/c++` _is_ g++10 already and since your minimal example works, the g++ version is not the problem. It's something else, most probably in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay the problem might be something pretty dumb. You did this:

```
set(CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

But those are not the variables you're looking for. It's [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) and [`CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED.html).

[`CXX_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_STANDARD.html) and `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` are target property names. If you want to use those, you should use [`set_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html) or [`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html). But at that point I'd suggest to look into [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html).

Next time, I'd suggest that you generate and inspect `compile_commands.json` to see what the compile command is actually being generated to. See also [`CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this problem on Ubuntu 22.04 with g++ 10.5 and cmake 3.22.1. My observation is that the lines below don't work:

```
set(CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CXX_STANDARD 20)
```

The solution for me was to add `-std=c++20` (or `-std=c++17`) to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. I was also able to get the result I wanted via `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 20)`.

Answer (score -1):

don't know if related GCC-9 but just in case:

> Runtime Library (libstdc++)
>
> - Using the types and functions in  does not require linking with -lstdc++fs now.
> - Incomplete support for the C++17 Filesystem library and the Filesystem TS on Windows.

ref: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html

Should try to see change in gcc-10

Comment: well, according to their question post, they _are_ using GCC 10.